# To get Custom attribute value present in <ul> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to fetch value of my custom attribute data-max-count present in my `ul` tag using jquery shown below.

```js
alert($(".no-styles que-list que-checkbox").data("max-count"));
alert($(".no-styles que-list que-checkbox").attr("data-max-count"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="2" data-que>
</ul>
```

Both of which has given me **undefined** as output, instead of value **2**.

Kindly suggest me ways to get my desired output.

Comment: Always check your selector works with `alert($(selector).length)` (or console.log) so you know that you are getting an element before trying to read from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, remove spaces when using multiple class selector.

```js
console.log($(".no-styles.que-list.que-checkbox").data('max-count'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="2" data-que>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selector is incorrect. See alert with your selector in my first alert and see the second selector ...

```js
alert($(".no-styles que-list que-checkbox").html());

alert($(".no-styles").data("max-count"));
alert($(".no-styles que-list que-checkbox").attr("data-maxcount"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-styles que-list que-checkbox" data-max-count="2" data-que>
<h1>sdf</h1>
</ul>
```